# Ambiguous record fields warning in GHC 9.2

Tags: haskell, ghc

With GHC 8.10 and 9.0 `foo (a :: Aaa)` was enough to disambiguate which field I want to use.
Since 9.2 I now get a warning (ambiguous-fields):

```
    The field ‘foo’ belonging to type Aaa is ambiguous.
    This will not be supported by -XDuplicateRecordFields in future releases of GHC.
    You can use explicit case analysis to resolve the ambiguity.
```

Consider the following snippet, having in mind that `Aaa` and `Bbb` come from an external library, **from the same module**:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

data Aaa = Aaa { foo :: Int }
data Bbb = Bbb { foo :: String }

a :: Aaa
a = Aaa 5

func1 :: Int
func1 = foo (a :: Aaa)

func2 :: Int
func2 = case a of
    Aaa{..} -> foo

func3 :: Int
func3 = case a of
    a'@Aaa{} -> foo a'
```

`func2` is the only warning-free solution. Is it really the best way currently?
`func3` completely ignores the case analysis (it's the same as just `foo a` which doesn't compile).

I'm using 9.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced a similar situation as yours, and finally, I found that `OverloadedRecordDot` can do this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedRecordDot #-}

func4 :: Int
func4 = a.foo
```